# How to trigger application to update cache if data changed at the storage (DB) by another application?

Tags: java, caching, orm

There are 2 java applications, both uses ORM and caching data at their own caches. Both are working with the same DB.

The 1st application changed some data at the DB, so how to let the 2nd application to update it's cache? Are there standard solutions for such issues?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of trying to synchronize the cached data between two server instances, why not centralize the caching instead using something like memcached/couchbase or redis? Using distributed caching with something like ehcache is far more complicated and error prone IMO vs centralizing the cached data using a caching server like those mentioned.

As an addendum to my original answer, when deciding what caching approach to use (in memory, centralized), one thing to take into account is the volatility of the data that is being cached.

If the data is stored in the DB, but does not change after the servers load it, then you don't even need synchronization between the servers. Just let them each load this static data into memory from the source and then go about their merry ways doing whatever it is they do. The data won't be changing, so no need to introduce a complicated pattern for keeping the data in sync between the servers.

If there is indeed a level of volatility in the data (like say you are caching looked up entity data from the DB in order to save hits to the DB), then I still think centralized caching is a better approach than in-memory distributed and synchronized caching. You just need to make sure that you use an appropriate expiration on the cached data to allow natural refresh of the data from time to time. Also, you might want to just drop the cached data from the centralized store when in the update path for a particular entity and then just let it be reloaded from the cache on the next request for that data. This is IMO better than trying to do a true write-through cache where you write to the underlying store as well as the cache. The DB itself might make tweaks to the data (via defaulting unsupplied values for example), and your cached data in that case might not match what's in the DB